# Squid - expire at specific time each day

Tags: redhat, squid

Does squid have an option to expire content at the same time every day as opposed to using the refresh_pattern to limit the age of a query?  I am currently running 2.6 on RHEL 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like `SquidPurge` in cron to purge at a specific time, see https://github.com/kormoc/SquidPurge for code